# View -> getParent() works fine in Android 2.3 but throwing NullPointerException in Android 4+

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception

```
private void swapLayouts(final int currentLayoutId, final int requestedLayout) {

    View layout = (View) this.findViewById(currentLayoutId);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) layout.getParent();
    int index = parent.indexOfChild(layout);

    parent.removeView(layout);
    layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(requestedLayout, parent, false);

    parent.addView(layout, index);
}
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown at `ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) layout.getParent();`

This is the LogCat output :

```
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blah.blah/com.blah.blah.VideoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at com.blah.blah.VideoActivity.swapLayouts(VideoActivity.java:287)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at com.blah.blah.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.java:75)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)    
09-30 19:04:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(4059):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: And `layout` is non-null?

Comment: In that case layout must be null, check for that.

Comment: I am pretty new to Java programming. I'm assuming it is non-null as I have initialized it with a valid layout id. The code works perfect in a Android 2.3.4 emulator and device but the exception is thrown on Android 4.0.3 and 4.3 emulators and a 4.3 device. Please ask for more info if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Add a condition in the log that checks for NPE on Layout and please post you logs here.

Comment: Hi first, Caution with your cast look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) But it's not the problem here. when is your function called ?

Comment: @GauravArora It says "Layout Failed".

Comment: @HoodVinci I'm calling the method in onCreate and in another method. The call at onCreate is the first one. I would like to reiterate that I am passing valid R.id.* and R.layout.* values.

Comment: I am not sure that's gonna solve your issue, but that always helps me avoid problem like this, try and use you application context. 
(something like ActivtyName.class.getApplicationContext().findViewById(<your layout name>)

Comment: @Ed_Fernando can you post the logcat file?

Comment: @Ed_Fernando, Even if you are using valid id's for some reason your layout variable can be null. Have you tested it's nullity? 
View layout = (View) this.findViewById(currentLayoutId); 
layout.getId();
This line should throw NPE.

Comment: Just one more question. Have you defined target sepcific xml files ?

Comment: @HoodVinci Spot on mate! It does throw a NPE. What are my options?

Comment: In your res/ folder have you more than one layout folder ?

Comment: Yes I do. I'm swapping a layout defined in a XML file under res/layouts with a layout that is a part of the main XML file. The main XML file has variants under res/layout-large, res/layout-sw600dp and res/layout-sw720dp.

Comment: It's there !! one of the id you are passing should not be defined in one of the xml file. it's not related to android version but rather to definition. Just check all your variants and verify ids carefully.

Comment: We solved it mate. You were right about the different layout folders. I overlooked the fact that the emulator and the actual device may access different layout folders. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to version of Android but rather to different layout folders.

Check  ids of all your xml variants file.

All ids you use by calling R.id.* in your java code should be defined in all variants of the same xml file.

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, getParent() return's the parent view if this view is an embedded child.

Is the View an embedded child? If not, getParent() will return null.

Comment: It is a child. It is working well on Android 2.x.x, the exception is thrown for Android 4.x.x only.